# AWS: Policy Conditional Statement Ignored

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-policies

So i m trying to run a policy but its never being invoked when setting the conditional to both true and false most likely missing something but when I ommit the conditional statement all together I get the desired policy enforcement.

Option 1: Conditional Statement false

```
    {
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            },
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
                "iam:ListAccountAliases",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys",
                "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary",
                "sts:GetSessionToken"
            ]
        }
```

Option 1: Conditional Statement false

```
    {
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            },
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
                "iam:ListAccountAliases",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys",
                "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary",
                "sts:GetSessionToken"
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent key is not present when an API or CLI command is called with long-term credentials, such as user access key pairs. Therefore we recommend that when you check for this key that you use the ...IfExists versions of the condition operators.